# SPSS K-means & R

Tags: r, k-means, spss

What would be the best function/package to use in R to try and replicate the K-means clustering method used in SPSS?  Here is an example of the syntax I would use in SPSS:

```
QUICK CLUSTER VAR1 TO VAR10       
   /MISSING=LISTWISE                  
   /CRITERIA=CLUSTER(5) MXITER(50) CONVERGE(.02)
   /METHOD=KMEANS(NOUPDATE)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just writing "kmeans in r" in Google you'll have [`kmeans` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/kmeans.html) as result. You can also take a look at [CRAN task views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html)

Comment: Yes but I"m not able to reproduce the same results using kmeans

Comment: K-means doesn't have a single correct solution. It depends both on the parameters for the particular analysis, as well as random decisions made as the algorithm searches for solutions. So as long as you're getting *similar* results in R and SPSS, it's not likely worth the effort to try and reproduce the *same* results. You can't even expect the identical results for two different runs of the same analysis in R.

Answer (score 0):

In SPSS, use the `/PRINT INITIAL` option. This will give you the initial cluster centers, which seem to be fixed in SPSS, but random in R (see `?kmeans`for parameter `centers`).

If you use the printed initial cluster centers from SPSS output and the `argument="Lloyd"` parameter in kmeans, you should get the same results (at least it worked for me, testing with several repetitions).

Example of an SPSS-output of the initial cluster centers:

```
           Cluster
           Cl1  Cl2  Cl3  Cl4
Var A      1    1    4    3
Var B      4    1    4    1
Var C      1    1    1    4
Var D      1    4    4    1
Var E      1    4    1    2
Var F      1    4    4    3
```

This table, replicated as matrix in R, with kmeans computation:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,4,3,4,1,4,1,1,1,1,4,1,4,4,1,1,4,1,2,1,4,4,3), nrow=4, ncol=6)
kmeans(na.omit(data.frame), centers=mat, iter.max=20, algorithm="Lloyd")
```

Be sure to use the same amount of maximum iterations in SPSS and R-kemans, and use Lloyd-method in R-kmeans.

However, I don't know whether it's better to have a fixed or a random choice of initial centers. I personally like the random choice, and compute a linear discriminant analysis with the found cluster groups to assess the classification accuracy, and rerun the kmeans clustering until I have a statisfying group classification.

Edit: I found [this posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30723/initializing-k-means-clustering) where the SPSS procedure of selecting initial clusters is described. Perhaps somebody knows of an R implementation?